# Prefer certain CPU architecture over others when loading native Android libs

Tags: android, native, chromebook, jnienv

I got some native libs that I load in my Android app. Usually clients support one architecture so when I check with `Build.SUPPORTED_ABIS`, I get something like `"armeabi-v7a","armeabi"`. Except on chromebooks. They seem to support two architectures. There I get `Build.SUPPORTED_ABIS = "x86","armeabi-v7a","armeabi"`. From what I understand, that means it supports both x86 and arm, but prefers x86.

Is there a way to specify for my app which architecture I would prefer it loads in this case? I would prefer it loads arm and not x86, even though x86 is at first position.

Answer (score 0):

put this code in build gradle

And get each abi separate app and also get univesal apk by changing build variants

```
splits {
  abi {
      enable true
      reset()
      include "x86", "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
      universalApk true

      }
   }
```

[Documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits)

Comment: Very interesting. I actually did not know about that. Although not quite what I wanted to figure out. I would like one APK with all the native libs in it, but I'm looking for a way to tell the device which lib to load if it supports more than one architecture. So a `x86` device would load the `x86` lib, but a device that supports `x86` **AND** `armeabi`, i want to be able to define which one I prefer it loads.

Comment: there is also a universal apk in this splits code ,it will generate all native libs and make apk